# How to create a child class that takes in a parent class and several other objects?

Tags: java

Given these:

```
Mark firstStudent = new Mark(...)

Mark firstStudentChecked = new VerifiedMark(firstStudent, object a, object b)
```

Object a and b can be any other thing. Above is just a sample code to express my idea. I am aware that VerifiedMark is probably a child class of Mark so it can be labelled as "VerifiedMark". But how can we construct the constructor of child class VerifiedMark? Usually, we would make use of super(...), but the parameter here for the child class is an object of parent.

Comment: unclear what you are asking? Generally it is no problem to pass objects of the same or super type to wherever you want to. What is the actual problem you are facing, what kind of error do you get? What does not work about the code?

Answer (score 1):

You can define another version of constructor for the parent class (which acts like a copy-constructor). For example,

```
class Mark {
    Object member;
    public Mark(Object m) {
        // this is regular constructor
        member = m;
    }
    public Mark(Mark m) {
        // this is copy constructor
        member = m.member;
    }
}
```

Now you can define VerifiedMark somewhat like below:

```
class VerifiedMark extends Mark {
    Object memberA, memberB;
    public VerifiedMark(Mark m, Object a, Object b) {
        super(m); // calling copy-constructor
        memberA = a;
        memberB = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `VerifiedMark` acts as a wrapper for `Mark`. In this case the subclass should hold a reference to the superclass like this:

```java
class VerifiedMark extends Mark {
    Mark m;
    Object a, b;

    public VerifiedMark(Mark m, Object a, Object b) {
        this.m = m;
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Given OP's code, the `VerifiedMark` constructor doesn't take the parameters the `Mark` constructor takes, therefore a call to `super()` is redundant (it is automatically called).